# Hi I need to write the Mock Test class for my webservice test class, i am stuck , please help me to create the mock call out in the APEX

Tags: apex, callout, apexmock

Below my class:

```
    @AuraEnabled
    public static ExtendedABRJsonResponse getExtendedABRDetails(String searchNumber, Boolean isABN) {

        ExtendedABRJsonResponse theDefaultResponse = new ExtendedABRJsonResponse();
        try{
            HTTPResponse response = makeCallout(searchNumber,isABN);
            System.debug('getExtendedABRDetails response***'+response);
            if(null != response) {
                System.debug('res body is::' + response.getBody());
                theDefaultResponse.ABRResponse = Util_ExtendedABRParser.parse(response.getBody());
                String anzsicCode =  theDefaultResponse.ABRResponse.anzsic.code.substring(0, 4);
                System.debug('***** anzsicCode substring is ***** ' + anzsicCode);
                
                List<Industry__c> industryList = [SELECT Id, Name, ANZSIC__c from Industry__c where ANZSIC__c = :anzsicCode];
                if (industryList.size() == 1){
                    theDefaultResponse.IndustryId = industryList.get(0).Id;
                    theDefaultResponse.IndustryName = industryList.get(0).Name;
                }

                theDefaultResponse.ABREntityType = getABREntityDetails(theDefaultResponse.ABRResponse.entityTypeName);
                return theDefaultResponse;
            }
        } catch(Exception exp) {
            System.debug('Exception is ::' + exp.getMessage());
            return theDefaultResponse;
        }
        return theDefaultResponse;
    }

    public static HTTPResponse makeCallout(String searchNumber, Boolean isABN) {
        HTTPResponse response=null;
        try {
            HttpCalloutService service = new HTTPCalloutService('ABR_Extended_MuleSoft');
            ExtendedABRJsonResponse theDefaultResponse = new ExtendedABRJsonResponse();
            System.debug('==searchNumber==' + searchNumber + '==isABN==' + isABN);
            if(null != searchNumber) {
                String encodedNumber = EncodingUtil.urlEncode(searchNumber.deleteWhitespace(), 'UTF-8');
                String finalURL = service.getEndpointURL();
                if(isABN)
                    finalURL +='/abn/' + encodedNumber;
                else 
                    finalURL +='/acn/' + encodedNumber;
                System.debug('==finalURL==' + finalURL);
                service.setEndpointURL(finalURL);
                
                response = service.sendRequest();
                System.debug('response***'+response);
                return response;
            }
        }
        catch(Exception exp) {
            System.debug('Exception is ::' + exp.getMessage());
            return response;
        }
        return response;
    }
```